# How start Telnet with systemctl in Debian

Tags: systemd

i to prove starting telnet with this command

> sudo systemctl start telnet.socket

but i comme; Failed to start telnet.socket: Unit telnet.socket not found.

So , i am little new with Linux as i have understand , the new's Linux version ,about a prozess new to start , now to use **systemd** . I can start telnet with

> sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd start

but i want to learn how to do this with systemd, because with it i have moreeeee possibility...

I have Debian Stretch

Comment: "you've read people talking about for systems based on RedHat, Arch Linux etc. Is that correct? ", yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## WARNING: Do not run a telnet server

Telnet is horribly insecure.  Do not run a telnet server on your computer.  You do not need to do this.

Instead you can use SSH.  If you were specifically interested in socket activation, like xinetd does, you can still do that with SSH.  Look at `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` and `ssh@.service`.

### How to run a telnet server

If you do not want to run `/etc/init.d/xinet start`, you could instead run `systemctl start xinetd`.  The first command would probably do exactly the same as the second anyway.  However, that is due to special code in Debian.  So I agree it is good to train yourself to use the `systemd` tools directly, when your system is using `systemd`.

However, it sounds like you are interested in writing a custom `telnet.socket` unit, which would match the behaviour you've read people talking about for systems based on RedHat, Arch Linux etc.

The source code for the Fedora package is currently available at https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/telnet/tree/master

Create the following files in `/etc/systemd/system/` -

### telnet.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Telnet Server Activation Socket
Documentation=man:telnetd(8)
    
[Socket]
ListenStream=23
Accept=true
    
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

### telnet@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Telnet Server
After=local-fs.target
    
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/in.telnetd
StandardInput=socket
```

Comment: " Don't run a telnet server on your computer. There is seriously no good reason to do so" , and a telnet-client ?

Comment: telnet client used to be a common way to connect e.g. to a web server and play with the text-based protocol.  this skips the telnet-specific protocol.  It may also be required for interacting with devices you have, which are old, or which used telnet because they were not intended to be at all secure and they thought it was easier for them to set up a telnet server.

Comment: I every time i ende to use telnet , stop it ......

Comment: @567hz I would still not recommend that, but it's good that you're taking such steps.

Comment: What would you recommned me ?

Comment: I recommend that SSH is the current standard for a remote shell :).  You could just disconnect the network when you use telnetd on localhost, or you could bind the telnetd to localhost only (IPv4 address 127.0.0.1).  If I wanted to play with telnetd artefacts, I might use one of my Virtual Machines.  One of the common VM networking options is effectively a NAT firewall.  It's also possible to set up a virtual network for VMs.  Also I haven't tended to expose much personal information to my VMs.

Comment: " There is seriously no good reason to do so." - Using encryption on amateur packet radio is a crime in the U.S.

Comment: @user515655 I don't want to be insulting, but I tried to avoid unnecessary complexity here due the asker's skill level with written English. I'm not really very good at doing that :-). I stand by my opinion that you should not start the stock telnetd server on a physical Debian install :-). The answer needed some such warning. And it's not my responsibility to provide details about how to contain it safely, avoid re-using the password for anything else... It would have been more interesting if you had linked some practical detail or example about the use of `telnetd` in this context :-).

Comment: Here's another reason to use telnet: I'm trying to connect legacy specialty hardware to a modern server backend. The hardware is from the early 90s, runs DOS, and can't run a SSH client.

Comment: @MiffTheFox Edited. Are we happy yet?